# getting caret position from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, caret

I am looking to validate an input to a DataGridView what has DataGridViewTextBoxCells. The textbox cells can be either signed or unsigned and int or double based on the column in focus. The issue that I am having is determining the caret position when a key is pressed.

For example if the cell allows signed doubles(caret <=> '^'):

- a valid keypress event   : ^12.3456 with a key press of '-' would give -12.3456
- an invalid keypress event: 12.34-56 with a key press of '-' would give 12.34-56

I have not been able to find anything that will allow me to access the caret position at the time of a keypress.

```
private void SomeGridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView DGV = SomeGridView;

    string curStr;

    bool isFirst = DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue == null;
    curStr = isFirst ? "" : DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
    Type type = DGV.CurrentCell.GetType();
    if (DGV.CurrentCell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxCell))
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell DGVTB = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGV.CurrentCell;
        //Not sure how to get caret here
    }

    switch ((GridDataEnum)DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case GridDataEnum.setpoint:
        case GridDataEnum.SlopePoint:
            e.Handled = !HelperUtils.isValidNumber(curStr, e.KeyChar, HelperUtils.TargetNumberTypeEnum.signedDouble);
            break;
        case GridDataEnum.lowerX:
        case GridDataEnum.upperX:
        case GridDataEnum.TransX:
        case GridDataEnum.constY:
            e.Handled = !HelperUtils.isValidNumber(curStr, e.KeyChar, HelperUtils.TargetNumberTypeEnum.unsignedDouble);
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The EditControlShowing event can be used to get the underlying TextBox control when the grid is in edit mode.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for it I found the answer thanks to LarsTech.

```
private void SomeGridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView DGV = SomeGridView;

    string curStr;

    bool isFirst = DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue == null;
    curStr = isFirst ? "" : DGV.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
    Type type = DGV.CurrentCell.GetType();
    if (DGV.CurrentCell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxCell))
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell DGVTB = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGV.CurrentCell;
        if (DGV.CurrentCell.EditType == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
            if(DGV.EditingControl != null)
                charIndex = ((TextBox)DGV.EditingControl).SelectionStart;
    }

    switch ((GridDataEnum)DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case GridDataEnum.setpoint:
        case GridDataEnum.SlopePoint:
            e.Handled = !HelperUtils.isValidNumber(curStr, e.KeyChar, HelperUtils.TargetNumberTypeEnum.signedDouble, charIndex);
            break;
        case GridDataEnum.lowerX:
        case GridDataEnum.upperX:
        case GridDataEnum.TransX:
        case GridDataEnum.constY:
            e.Handled = !HelperUtils.isValidNumber(curStr, e.KeyChar, HelperUtils.TargetNumberTypeEnum.unsignedDouble, charIndex);
            break;
    }
}
```